# java.lang.NumberFormatException on the JMeter console logs

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

When I am trying to browse the JTL file to the aggregate report, I am getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException` on the console logs. The load run was for 2hrs for 3 of the POST APIs. I am currently using JMeter 5.4.3 and this has created a literal pain. I am not able to analyze the report. PFB attached complete logs:

```
2022-06-04 14:57:45,557 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2022-06-04 14:57:45,558 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2022-06-04 14:57:45,558 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2022-06-04 14:57:45,558 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
2022-06-04 14:57:45,558 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
2022-06-04 14:57:45,558 INFO o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/css is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.CssParser
2022-06-04 14:57:47,538 INFO o.j.r.PluginManager: Plugins Status: [jpgc-graphs-basic=2.0, jpgc-functions=2.1, jpgc-casutg=2.10, jpgc-dummy=0.4, jpgc-ffw=2.0, tilln-iso8583=1.2, jpgc-fifo=0.2, mqtt-xmeter=2.0.2, mqtt-sampler=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, bzm-parallel=0.11, jpgc-perfmon=2.1, jpgc-plugins-manager=1.7, bzm-random-csv=0.8, jpgc-tst=2.5, jmeter-core=5.4.3, jmeter-ftp=5.4.3, jmeter-http=5.4.3, jmeter-jdbc=5.4.3, jmeter-jms=5.4.3, jmeter-junit=5.4.3, jmeter-java=5.4.3, jmeter-ldap=5.4.3, jmeter-mail=5.4.3, jmeter-mongodb=5.4.3, jmeter-native=5.4.3, jmeter-tcp=5.4.3, jmeter-components=5.4.3, jpgc-standard=2.0]
2022-06-04 14:58:17,839 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
2022-06-04 14:58:17,849 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 5.0
2022-06-04 14:58:17,850 INFO o.a.j.s.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
2022-06-04 14:58:17,854 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
2022-06-04 14:58:17,854 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
2022-06-04 14:58:17,854 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
2022-06-04 14:58:17,854 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
2022-06-04 14:58:17,855 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2022-06-04 14:58:26,568 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Error parsing field 'allThreads' at line 40654. java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "81654269947015"
2022-06-04 14:58:26,568 WARN o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: Problem reading JTL file: /home/naveen/Desktop/testresults.jtl
org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterError: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "81654269947015"
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.CSVSaveService.makeResultFromDelimitedString(CSVSaveService.java:378) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.CSVSaveService.processSamples(CSVSaveService.java:170) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.loadExistingFile(ResultCollector.java:379) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.gui.AbstractVisualizer.stateChanged(AbstractVisualizer.java:247) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FilePanelEntry.fireFileChanged(FilePanelEntry.java:140) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.FilePanelEntry.actionPerformed(FilePanelEntry.java:155) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635) [?:?]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843) [?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918) [?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547) [?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772) [?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) [?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743) [?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "81654269947015"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.save.CSVSaveService.makeResultFromDelimitedString(CSVSaveService.java:319) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 1):

**1654269947015** is a timestamp which converts to Friday, June 3, 2022 3:25:47.015 PM GMT.
What you have is **"81654269947015"** and **"8"** in the beginning seems wrong here.
Search your JTL file and remove the leading **"8"**, save the file and try feeding to the report again.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) is corrupt somewhere somehow

At the line `40654` of your results file JMeter tries to parse `81654269947015` as the number of active threads and the number doesn't fit into Java [Integer Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) as it's larger than Integer's [maximum value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

If line `40654` is the last line of your file try removing it manually using your favorite text editor.

The fact that JMeter fails to write a proper .jtl file most probably means that JMeter had a problem, i.e. it was overloaded hence I don't think you can trust the results. So:

1. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
2. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)
3. Make sure that JMeter has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. The JMeter jtl file was overridden by many tests and hence it was not giving a proper o/p file and created problems while loading. Re-running the script by providing the new name for the jtl file solved the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).